# clockwise or counter clockwise in 3D

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have two different situation that I need to make distinction between them (shown in the picture). In other words, in (A) points 3 and 4 are in right and left side of line 1-2. However, in case (B) they are not. I need to distinguish this problem. I was thinking about clockwise and counterclockwise. in case A 1-2-3 is clockwise and 1-2-4 is counterclockwise, however in (B) they are both (1-2-4),(1-2-3) counterclockwise. the problem is how to detect it. In Matlab I used 'polyccw' code but it not working for 3D.
my main problem is how to find if to branches are both in right or both in left side of main branch(1-2). 
[image]

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: If you rotate $B$ in 3D it becomes similar to $A$. How are the two pictures different at all?

Comment: You should remember from high school organic chemistry class that a molecule is chiral (different left-right handed) only if it has a locus (a carbon atom) with four DIFFERENT ligands attached. In this example, your 2 only has 3 different things attached (assuming 1, 3, and 4 are distinguishable) so it isn't chiral.

Answer (score 1):

@Hoda,
Thanks for your response, 
No, the picture is not the same at all

The fact is that we can't determine clockwise or counterClockwise orientation in 3D. But how can I Distinguish between two models,
I was thinking to use this logic,

v1=point2-point1
v2=point3-point2
v3=point4-point2,

then compare cross product of c1=(v1, v2) and c2=(v1,v3).
In a planar 3D which all 4 points are in the same plane, we can say that :
if angel between c1 and c2 is 0 = case (B)
if angel between c1 and c2 is 180 = case (A)
However in non-planar case we cannot chose a specific angle between two vector to compare them, that is my problem here

Comment: You could check the sign of the dot product between $c_1$ and $c_2$, which is positive when the angle is between 0 and 90, and negative when the angle is between 90 and 180.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rahul